# The CSS Selectors' 'Universal Selector' and 'Type Selector' examples have been deleted, can this be undone?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-examples, deleted-examples

Yesterday a user deleted the Universal Selector and Type Selector examples, claiming that these were "duplicate content". This change was approved by a user with just 152 reputation. However I can't see what these were supposed to be a duplicate of.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/73709

The official CSS Selector documentation breaks Selectors down into 7 distinct categories:

- Type Selector
- Universal Selector
- Attribute Selectors
- Class Selectors
- ID Selectors
- Pseudo-Classes
- Pseudo-Elements

Thanks to this user's approved change, we now have examples for all but the first two, whereas before the change all 7 were covered.

As far as I'm aware there's no way I can rollback or undelete examples, so could these please get added back in?

Comment: That same user [proposed completely made up nonsense](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/65311) into the Combinators example that I then had to [seek approval to get removed](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/69029). The real question, though, is why we need a Selectors topic that essentially mirrors the official Selectors spec, examples and all, and throws in a whole slew of misused terminology and other factually incorrect information for good measure.

Comment: (Side note, holy crap, [I'm almost 10k in \[css-selectors\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-selectors/topusers). I need to get a job.)

Comment: @BoltClock and here I am with only 236/400 towards the silver badge. A certain user always beats me to those questions...

Comment: I've been rejecting a lot of stuff by that user... he keeps re-submitting the same edits over and over again if they get rejected. An unwieldy solution is to just copy all the content that he removed and add it back in an edit and, since you have a gold badge in [tag:css] you shouldn't need to wait for a review. That edit was approved on August 2nd, by a user with a score of 6 in [tag:css]... luckily now there are more stringent requirements and a random user with almost no score can no longer unilaterally approve edits.