# Are bad documentation changes getting passed because of inexperienced reviewing?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Currently everybody (with 150+ reputation points I believe) can review changes to documentation. This makes for a fast documentation review process. However, how do we stop users with no knowledge of the change they are approving of doing just that?

Say somebody decides it's a nice idea to change a C++ example for a certain topic. He does a good job of explaining it, but leaves out some important points and maybe uses incorrect or bad code in his example. The change gets put up for review and one experienced C++ user sees it's bad and rejects it, but then there come five other users who have no knowledge of C++, and they accept it, because to them it seems like the example was improved.

At the moment this is not a big problem, but I can see it becoming really troublesome as the documentation gets refined. How do we avoid getting into a — bad change gets approved, experienced user changes it back, somebody messes it up again, moderator fixes it — cycle?

Comment: Subject level knowledge is not required or expected for the other review queues, why would it be expected for the documentation queue?

Comment: @JoeW Other review queues at least have a reputation threshold. But adding a knowledge requirement (like only silver or gold badge owners) already has been discussed before, with mixed opinions.

Comment: @Tom This one also does, it just happens to be the lowest of the review queues at 100 rep. That might be because the feature is still in beta and the level has not been fully tuned. The real question is how do you prove someone has knowledge in a subject? Or prevent someone with no real knowledge but a high tag score from simple questions from reviewing?

Comment: @JoeW That is true, the numbers are almost always lower in beta. Maybe something simple like 1 positively received question or answer in that tag? That is not hard to get but would insure the user has at least some interest/knowledge in the field.

Comment: @JoeW As I understand it, even users whose 100 rep comes from the association bonus can review Documentation entries. Meaning it is theoretically possible to review Docs entries while knowing literally **nothing** about programming.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Isn't that the purpose of the association bonus to give access to site functionality? If that is an issue the rep level could be increased but that would still not change the knowledge issue.

Comment: @JoeW As far as I'm concerned, the rep level for reviewing Docs should indeed be increased - at least higher than the association bonus. 500, the same for First Posts and Late Answers, seems a fine enough threshold to me.

Comment: @JoeW *"Or prevent someone with no real knowledge but a high tag score from simple questions from reviewing?"* Just because we can't keep off every clueless person from reviewing, doesn't mean we should allow (almost) everyone to review instead ;P. Decreasing the number of bad reviews is always a good idea and that's way we have review audits.

Comment: @Tom Now that you mention audits.... one thing that might help with the knowledge issue, is harder review audits. Not just testing if people Approve randomly generated gibberish, but, for example, use a deeply downvoted answer as an audit. Approve the answer, despite its (probable) bad content? Audit failed.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575

Comment: See [Should people who've never asked or answered a question for C be allowed to review C documentation changes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339137/)

Comment: Absolutely. Bad suggested edits might be getting passed for the same reason. should we do something about either?

Comment: @JoeW Because documentation is different from editing someone's post. Documentation edits change the *meaning*, while proposed edits which change the meaning should be rejected. They're very different. Subject knowledge *is* required when reviewing documentation changes. SE doesn't seem to agree with this, which is why we end up with a huge amount of rubbish and explicitly incorrect documentation.

Comment: I would like to recommend a change. Only people having a certain score in a particular tag should be allowed to review document changes pertaining to that tag. If such a change can be incorporated it would be highly beneficial

Comment: Some people, when confronted with ["GetRowEnumerator - Gets the rows enumerator,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) think "I know, I'll let literally anyone approve content." Now they have two problems.

Comment: "At the moment this is not a big problem" Oh, [you sweet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331611/the-css-selectors-universal-selector-and-type-selector-examples-have-been-d#comment379149_331611) [summer child](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334638/documentation-is-on-its-way-to-becoming-the-next-w3schools).

Comment: "How do we avoid getting into a — bad change gets approved, experienced user changes it back, somebody messes it up again, moderator fixes it — cycle?" We're not going to be able to avoid that. From [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330187), "if the factually incorrect information was approved for Documentation in the first place then enough people have been misled by this misinformation that someone else might propose the same misinformation back into the Documentation topic at a later date and someone else might approve it again"

Comment: Reputation absolutely not ensure a specific subject knowledge. Who can pretend knowing all topics even with 100k+ reputaiton level? But a new comer could be an expert in some topics.

Comment: "At the moment this is not a big problem" Surely you have not read the C++ Documentation then...

Comment: I have to admit I was wrong when saying it that. I have read some more of the documentation and it is apparently a lot worse than I had thought. I think it will be like this at least till the end of beta. At the moment they are still testing and working out the kinks in the documentation feature and for that the more users the better. I am sure the reputation requirements will get raised once documentation is out of beta.

Answer (score 5):

> Are bad documentation changes getting passed because of inexperienced reviewing?

I just checked the [activity in the Python tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python?tab=activity) and while most of the edits seem to improve existing content, some seem to introduce plain wrong information.

However, it is difficult to estimate if these bad changes are passed because of inexperience (low rep?) of the reviewers. My observation is that reviewers typically have 200-4000 rep points and there is no clear correlation between rep and passing bad changes visible to me. Maybe there is, one would have to investigate more thoroughly.

So the answer is a clear: It's possible.

> How do we avoid getting into a — bad change gets approved, experienced user changes it back, somebody messes it up again, moderator fixes it — cycle?

In this case I would see three possibilities:

- Don't rely on thorough reviewing, weed the mistakes out later. After all everyone can edit. Possibly add a penalty for suggesting and positively reviewing edits that get rejected later.
- Increase rep limit necessary for reviewing, possibly add some tag score limit and maybe adapt it dynamically for each tag to make sure, a timely review is possible.
- Audits, audits, audits and block reviewers who failed audits. Feed the audits from the bad edits which are rejected or rolled back.

The more mature content is, the more restrictive you want to become.

Comment: Btw. bad reviews are not the only problem of Documentation. Low activity in general and very specific design are also among them..